# Carbon file not found Vagrant

Tags: laravel, namespaces, composer-php, vagrant, php-carbon

laravel/framework v5.5.37

I git cloned someone's project on my machine. Using Vagrant with Homestead box. I get this error:
[image]

I have not made in changes to the code. On his environment it works and on production it works as well. When I search for Carbon, it is only in the composer.lock file, not the composer.json file. What does that mean? I thought that meant he had globally installed nesbot/carbon on his machine so when i did composer global require "nesbot/carbon" I still get the error.

How is it possible it is in lock but not in json? Im doing all of this in the vagrant ssh.

Comment: Just to confirm, have you run `composer install` on your new copy? The file being in composer.lock and not composer.json probably just means it's an *indirect dependency* - that is, something which is listed in composer.json needs carbon, so Composer follows the dependency graph and decides to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import Carbon:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

after declaring your namespace in controller.

for example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon; // here added the line
```

It doesn't seem to be "your" fault, it seems like bug in code. Carbon is used by Laravel framework under the hood so you don't need to have it in your `composer.json` file .

Comment: While this would explain the error, it doesn't explain why it seems to work on other copies of the same codebase.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm almost 100% sure  it doesn't. It just matter that probably bothy developers are not testing exactly same url in this app.

Comment: hard to imagine a reasonable server configuration that would allow you to use Carbon from a controller without a use statement pointing to it first

Comment: True, that is an entirely plausible explanation. I was just wondering if there was some magic pre-processing going on or something which might cause this. But in the absence of more information, Occam's razor suggests "not testing the same code".

Comment: Thanks, weird that piece was not there.